# Atlas and Vidalia report different information about Tor relay

Tags: relays, vidalia, atlas

While Atlas reports

```
Nickname    Bandwidth   Uptime  IP      
lavizrap    102.4 KB/s  2h 7m   24.134.58.142
```

(https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/lavizrap)

Vidalia Network Overview reports

```
lavizrap (Online)
Ort: Deutschland
IP-Adresse: 24.134.58.142
Bandbreite: 40.00 KB/s
Läuft seit: 3 hours 10 mins 
Zuletzt aktualisiert: 2013-12-03 07:12:36 GMT
```

Why 102.4 KB/s. vs 40.00 KB/s
and Uptime: 2h 7m vs. 3 hours 10 mins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Atlas, you are seeing consensus information from the Tor network, as retrieved via Onionoo. It is based on reports to and measurements by Tor network authority servers. It is a periodic report, and does not necessarily reflect the instantaneous state of your relay (recent changes you've made will take a while to show). This is the kind of information that other Tor users' Tor Browser Bundles will rely upon for selecting relays.

With Vidalia, you are seeing a direct local report from your relay. The local reporting shows your configured settings (BandwidthRate, MaxAdvertisedBandwidth, etc.). It reflects the immediate state of your relay. It can also show close to actual byte counts sent and received by your relay, as well as other private details.

The fine manual and other documentation for Atlas https://atlas.torproject.org/#about and Onionoo https://www.torproject.org/projects/onionoo.html explain more about the network reporting.